# Mixing IO with State computation

Tags: haskell

As an exercise I'm writing a command-line RPN calculator in Haskell. The idea is it will prompt for input (a number or operator) and print out the new stack. My plan is to store the list of numbers in a state monad, and perform calculations against that list. For example:

```
> 4
[4]
> 3
[3,2]
> 5
[5,3,2]
> +
[8, 2]
```

and so on.

I'm starting with just trying to build up the list in the State monad with input & output on each entry. I'm already stuck due to the combination of IO & State in the same function. My problem is, I also need to recurse on the input, to keep the prompt going after the first number is input.

Here is my code so far:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State

addEntry :: Int -> State [Int] Int
addEntry entry = do
  entries <- get
  put (entry : entries)
  return entry

mainLoop :: [Int] -> IO ()
mainLoop entries = do
  entry <- readLn
  newEntries <- execState (addEntry entry) entries
  print newEntries
  mainLoop newEntries

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ mainLoop []
```

and here is the compiler error I'm currently getting:

```
src/Main.hs@14:28-14:42 Couldn't match type [Int] with ‘IO [Int]’
Expected type: State (IO [Int]) Int
  Actual type: State [Int] Int …
src/Main.hs@14:44-14:51 Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [Int]’ with actual type [Int] …
```

Any tips on how to structure these functions such that I'm not combining IO & State?

Comment: Have you considered using `StateT [Int] IO Int` instead of `StateT [Int] Identity Int` (which is the same as `State [Int] Int`)?  Then you could use `liftIO` to lift IO actions to the `StateT [Int] IO` monad and perform stateful operations and IO actions in the same do-block.

Comment: Although, you can get this to compile if you add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` to the top of your file, then change `addEntry`'s type signature to `MonadState [Int] m => Int -> m Int`, then change `execState` to `execStateT`, although you also have a compiler error with `print $ mainLoop []`, should just be `mainLoop []` since it does the printing itself and doesn't return anything.  [Like this](https://gist.github.com/7331ab8d54ba17d82cae)

Comment: Is it pretty common in real world applications to actually pass IO-wrapped values into your state? Unless the actual state computation relied on IO for some reason, it feels pretty dirty to me.

Comment: The entire point of monad transformers is to be able to combine the effects of different kinds of monads together into a larger "stack".  You aren't passing IO wrapped values as your state, you're performing `IO` actions and `StateT` actions at the same time.  Since you look like you're wanting to write what amounts to a REPL for an RPN calculator, which means you want to keep up with a state while performing IO.  You can move all the actual RPN-ing to pure functions and just use `StateT MyState IO` whenever you need to get values and output values.

Comment: The usual way to do this would look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/1706eed3c56c309bbb75).  This separates out which sections can do IO and which can just do stateful operations.  Using the `MonadState` context makes these functions more easily composable, and it keeps the IO actions all inside `rpnREPL`

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and example! I think I will be using that as a reference quite a bit as I progress through this exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're using state because you want to try it out, but you can achieve the state itself without the 'bother' of the state monad.

```
module Main where

addEntry :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
addEntry = (:)

mainLoop :: [Int] -> IO ()
mainLoop entries = do
  entry <- readLn
  let newEntries = addEntry entry entries
  print newEntries
  mainLoop newEntries

main :: IO ()
main = mainLoop []
```

Comment: I did want to try it out, I'm trying to get more comfortable with monads in general. But more than that, I want to keep things as simple as possible. So this is very helpful!